# jQuery isn't chaning image source in background

Tags: jquery, image, websocket, src

I'm using a WebSocket. I've set an event listener for incoming messages. When a message comes in, I want to change a source of a image (with id's). That's only working when the div was visible once.

```
socket = new WebSocket("url:port", "base64");
socket.addEventListener("message", function(event) {

    message = atob(event.data);

        var temperature = message[4]+message[5]+message[6];
        temperature = temperature.replace("0", "");

        $("#"+id+"-img").attr('src', 'assets/img/red_temperature.png');


        var date = new Date;
        var seconds = date.getSeconds();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var hour = date.getHours();

        if(hour <= 9) 
          hour = "0"+hour;
        if(minutes <= 9) {
          minutes = "0"+minutes;
        }
        if(seconds <= 9) {
          seconds = "0"+seconds;
        }

        $("#temperatureslastupdate").html("Letzte Aktualisierung: "+hour+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);

        $("#"+id+"-temperature").html(temperature+" °C");
      break;

      default:
        break;

    }

    protokoll.append(message+"<br>");

  });
```

The funny thing is: Change the html of the last-update-div is working. append() to the protocol is also working.

What's the hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
 $("#"+id+"-img").load('assets/img/red_temperature.png');
```

Comment: Because it must load the image from server. Static change in src tag will not reflect

Comment: There's a default picture first. So, if I try your suggestion, it doesn't work. How to replace?

Comment: Solved the problem. It was my mistake